# Set custom display-names for enumerate items, then refer to them

Tags: enumerate

In an `enumerate` environment, I'd like to:

- provide custom display-names for items,
- `\label` these items,
- `\ref` these items later, and have it display the display-name.

I found out that I can modify the display-name of an `\item` by passing it as an optional argument. However, after this change `\ref` does not print anything anymore.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item \label{Orange} It's orange.
\item \label{Round} It's round.
\item \label{Great} It's great.
\end{enumerate}
By properties \ref{Orange}, \ref{Round}, and \ref{Great} the item is a fruit.

\begin{enumerate}[label=Orangeaaa, leftmargin=*]
\item[(Orange)] \label{OrangeB} It's orange.
\item[(Round)] \label{RoundB} It's round.
\item[(Great)] \label{GreatB} It's great.
\end{enumerate}
By properties \ref{OrangeB}, \ref{RoundB}, and \ref{GreatB} the item is a fruit.
    
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

I'd like this to read `By properties (Orange), (Round), and (Great), the item is a fruit.`.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Do you have many of these non-standard lists, or would an ad-hoc solution suffice (if you have only one of these lists)?

Comment: I have just one list.

Comment: Don't mix the use of [`enumerate`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumerate) and [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example provides `\setitem{<label>}` that sets `\item[<label>]` and updates `\@currentlabel` as well - the macro needed for `\label`s.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  \item \label{Orange} It's orange.
  \item \label{Round} It's round.
  \item \label{Great} It's great.
\end{enumerate}
By properties \ref{Orange}, \ref{Round}, and \ref{Great} the item is a fruit.

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setitem}[1]{\item[#1]\def\@currentlabel{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{enumerate}[label=Orangeaaa, leftmargin=*]
  \setitem{(Orange)} \label{OrangeB} It's orange.
  \setitem{(Round)} \label{RoundB} It's round.
  \setitem{(Great)} \label{GreatB} It's great.
\end{enumerate}
By properties \ref{OrangeB}, \ref{RoundB}, and \ref{GreatB} the item is a fruit.
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great:)